# Can I mirror a folder's contents as it's changed in OSX?

Tags: macos, symbolic-link, mirroring

**TL;DR**

How can I mirror the contents of a Mac OSX directory, to another directory on my hard drive?

---

I have a Dropbox folder that I use on all of my computers (a few Windows machines and a Macbook.)  As I'm sure you are aware, Dropbox does a pretty good job of keeping all of this content synced across all of my PCs.

What I would like to do is create a folder within my Dropbox folder that I can use for storing resource files for an iOS project.  I have a few photo editing tools that I'd like to use on my primary, Windows machine.  What I am hoping to do is be able to work on these files in Windows, save them, let Dropbox do it's thing, come over to my Mac and *viola!*, everything is synced and "just works" in XCode.

The problem is that my iOS project is stored in another directory location on my Mac hard drive outside of Dropbox.  What I want to do is mirror all of the contents in my Dropbox resource folder to the resource folder of my iOS project.  Can this be done and, if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look up [Symbolic Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). These are supported on OS X, Linux, and Windows Vista/7, and do exactly what you want.

You would copy the relavent files into a folder in DropBox, and then create a symlink at the original location which points back to the files now in your DropBox.

You can use symlinks to link files or directories, though it'll probably be easiest to link a single directory or a few directories instead of each individual file.

Comment: Yes, I actually want all of the contents of one folder (including it's sub folders) to mirror (or be symbolically linked) to another folder.  Thanks for the reference to Wikipedia.  It looks like the code that they provide will do the trick.